# How do I name my pet in Cube World?

Tags: cube-world

Question says it all really. I know it's possible as I've previously named a pet but I've lost the link telling me how it's done so I have a cat named Zeus and a penguin named Penguin.

I seem to recall it was done with something obvious like typing/petname but I can't put my finger on it.

**How do I name pets in Cube World?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is `/namepet` and capitalization does matter (it needs to be all lower case) even though its very hard to see it in the font the game uses.

Comment: Cheers muchly indeed.

Comment: I assume I will need to have the pet in question active in order to rename it?

Comment: @shanodin That you do need, it will rename whichever pet is active.